# Loop through array of objects and create an array of true values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling to get this pass from last couple of days. But could not figure out how to solve this. I'm working on a react project. Below is my problem

```js
var array = [
    {name: 'a', value: false}, 
    {name: 'b', value: false}, 
    {name: 'c', value: false}, 
    {name: 'd', value: true}, 
    {name: 'e', value: false}
]
```

I tried Javascript `filter` and `forEach` methods but couldn't figure out the perfect solution for get an array with the `names` of the objects whose `value` is `true`. Expected output for previous sample of data should be:

```
var output = ['d']
```

Comment: array.filter(item => item.value).map(ele => ele.name)

Comment: Please consider adding what you've tried. Just saying you couldn't figure it out is too vague and stops you from getting feedback on the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) followed by [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`filter` checks for `value === true`, and them `map` will return the desired field.

```js
var array = [{name: 'a', value: false}, {name: 'b', value: false}, {name: 'c', value: false}, {name: 'd', value: true}, {name: 'e', value: false}]

var ans = array.filter(function(o){
  return o.value
}).map(function(o){
  return o.name;
});

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) iterating only once on the array:

```js
var array = [
    {name: 'a', value: false},
    {name: 'b', value: false},
    {name: 'c', value: false},
    {name: 'd', value: true},
    {name: 'e', value: false}
]

let res = array.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    curr.value && acc.push(curr.name);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Or using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and `destructuring`:

```js
var array = [
    {name: 'a', value: false},
    {name: 'b', value: false},
    {name: 'c', value: false},
    {name: 'd', value: true},
    {name: 'e', value: false}
]

let res = array.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => value ? [...acc, name] : acc, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great reminder of the spread operator option - and easy to read format ;)

Comment: @stever It is nice, but note that in this case, the version with the `spread syntax` will decrease performance, that is why I offer it as a second chance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use only [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve this. You add to the acc array only when the value is true.

```js
const  array = [{name: 'a', value: false}, {name: 'b', value: false}, {name: 'c', value: false}, {name: 'd', value: true}, {name: 'e', value: false}];

const res = array.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => value ? acc.concat(name) : acc, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `for` loop

```js
var array = [{name: 'a', value: false}, {name: 'b', value: false}, {name: 'c', value: false}, {name: 'd', value: true}, {name: 'e', value: false}]

let op = []

for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if(array[i].value){
    op.push(array[i].name)
  }
}

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Object.values()** and **find()** we can iterate over the values and return the name in an array

```
var array = [
    {name: 'a', value: false},
    {name: 'b', value: false},
    {name: 'c', value: false},
    {name: 'd', value: true},
    {name: 'e', value: false}
]

const result = arr => [Object.values(arr).find(val => val.value).name];

console.log(result(array)); // [ 'd' ]
```